# Assign the value from a text field into an int variable to do some math with other variables and then return it?

Tags: ios, xcode, variables, textfield, assign

The code showing here assigns the value of an variables to the text field I want to do the opposite of that. 
_Initial.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", init];

The opposite of the code above. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The opposite of that would be getting converting string to float. You can do it with this

```
init = [_Initial.text floatValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should search for an answer before you ask a question.

```
NSString *intString = @"123";
NSString *floatString = @"456.789";
int intVal = [intString intValue];
float floatVal = [floatString floatValue];
printf("%i %f\n",intVal,floatVal);
```

Comment: Thank you, I actually found another way too. I tried looking everywhere but i couldnt find anything only after i posted the question i came up with something, thank you though